# Laravel : Split URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following url :

http://PenTest.dev/store?user_id=1

Basically this opens a pop via JavaScript.

The operations/logic is in a function and at the ends i am redirecting like this,

`return redirect()->back()`

Which again returns to the old url,

What i want is to redirect `PenTest.dev/store`

Is there any way to redirect to the above url.

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but you can 'split' urls with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: can you show us your route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [Redirects in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects)

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```